# Please help me with centering a text box

Tags: html

I'm new to HTML and working on a website where I need this text box to appear in the center as it looks rather odd on the left hand side (please help me make edits to the html as well:

```
<!-- Job Opportunities -->
<div class="wrapper wrapper-style3">
    <article id="careers">
        <header>
                <h2>Careers</h2>

        </header>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="12u"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="4u">
                    <article class="box box-style2">
                            <h3>Work With Us</h3>

                        <p>We are looking for enthusiastic, detail-orientated professionals to assist in our continued growth. As a small firm, we reward flexibility with excellent conditions and an enjoyable working environment. Rapid career progression is possible for candidates demonstrating the right characteristics. Please contact us, enclosing a CV, for details of our current vacancies.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            </article>
        </div>
```

Comment: You're missing a closing article and div tag in your example. Also, what CSS have you tried?

Comment: Miss placed closing article tag

Comment: Yes I've added the tags, I just need the text box to appear in the center. I'm doing this through notepad, minor fix job but not part of my forte.

Answer (score 0):

**Create css class in `<head>`'s `<style>` element:**

```
.centered { width:70%; margin: 0 auto; }
```

**Add css class to div:**

```
<!-- Job Opportunities -->
<div class="wrapper wrapper-style3 centered">
    <article id="careers">
        <header>
                <h2>Careers</h2>

        </header>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="12u"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="4u">
                    <article class="box box-style2">
                            <h3>Work With Us</h3>

                        <p>We are looking for enthusiastic, detail-orientated professionals to assist in our continued growth. As a small firm, we reward flexibility with excellent conditions and an enjoyable working environment. Rapid career progression is possible for candidates demonstrating the right characteristics. Please contact us, enclosing a CV, for details of our current vacancies.</p>
                    </article>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </article>
</div>
```

**JsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/3Ly1s3tv/

Comment: Thanks but the text box is still appearing on the left hand side.

Comment: This is one section of a static website, where there are six boxes in each section, aligned together in two groups of three. Since the Careers Section has only one box, I want it to be centered.

Comment: This forum is not meant to be a tutorial website. I suggest you do a search on how css can be used to center HTML elements.